# Timer cuenta regresiva C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity2d

Hola estoy haciendo un juego en Unity el cual debe tener un cronómetro que empieza en 60, cuando llegue a 30 debe cambiar el color de las letras a rojo y cuando llega a 0 debe empezar a aumentar y no pasar a negativo hasta ahora llevo el conteo inicial pero no logro hacer la segunda parte que el cronómetro se devuelva.

```
using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using UnityEngine.UI;

 public class Timmer : MonoBehaviour {

     public Text Tempo; 
     public float tiempo = 0.0f;



     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {
         tiempo -= Time.deltaTime;
         Tempo.text = "Tiempo:" + " " + tiempo.ToString ("f0");

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No trabajo con Unity tan seguido, pero puedes implementar una solución vaga como la siguiente:

```
public class Timmer : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Text Tempo;
    public float Tiempo = 0.0f;
    public bool DebeAumentar = false;

    void Update() 
    {
        if (DebeAumentar) 
            Tiempo += Time.deltaTime; 
            // Primero se comprueba que sea falso el tener que aumentar.
        else 
        {
            if (Tiempo <= 0.0f)  // Comprueba si es menor o igual a cero.
            { DebeAumentar = true; } // Para volver true a este.
            else 
            { Tiempo -= Time.deltaTime; } // De lo contrario, sigue bajando.
        }
        if (Tiempo <= 30.0f) 
        { Tempo.color = Color.Red; } // Comprueba para cambiar el color del text. 
        else { Tempo.color = Color.Green; } // Vuelve a verde cuando aumente...

        Tempo.text = "Tiempo:" + " " + Tiempo.ToString ("f0");
    }
}
```

Para algo simple debe funcionar, tambien se puede mejorar el código, está bien explicado en comentarios.

**EDIT**: He hecho una pequeña mejora en el código para mejorar su legibilidad, pero no sé si será compatible con tu versión de C#, lo he probado en C#6:

```
public class Timmer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text Tempo;
    public float Tiempo = 0.0f;
    public bool DebeAumentar = false;

    void Update()
    {
        // Se comprueba si debe aumentar el valor primero...
        DebeAumentar = (Tiempo <= 0.0f)  ? true : false;

        // Luego se efectua el aumento.
        if (DebeAumentar) Tiempo += Time.deltaTime;
        else Tiempo -= Time.deltaTime;

        // Se asigna el color dependiendo del tiempo restante.
        Tempo.color  = (Tiempo <= 30.0f) ? Color.Red : Color.Green;

        Tempo.text = "Tiempo:" + " " + Tiempo.ToString ("f0");
    }
}
```

Debería de funcionar de igual o mejor forma.

He de utilizar el operador [ternario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_ternario) en esta segunda implementación y es representado de la siguiente forma:

```
Var = (Condición) ? (Si cumple la condición, se asigna este valor) : (De lo contrario, este);
```

Es algo así como una *"Asignación condicional"*. Espero ayude.

Answer (score 0):

Fuente: [Simple timer](https://answers.unity.com/questions/351420/simple-timer-1.html)

```
public class Countdown: MonoBehaviour {
     public int duration = 60;
     public int timeRemaining;
     public bool isCountingDown = false;
     public void Begin()
     {
         if (!isCountingDown) {
             isCountingDown = true;
             timeRemaining = duration;
             Invoke ( "_tick", 1f );
         }
     }

     private void _tick() {
         timeRemaining--;
         if(timeRemaining > 0) {
             Invoke ( "_tick", 1f );
         } else {
             isCountingDown = false;
         }
     }
 }
```